# Move data from row to another row within a group of specified rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have this dataset that I want to transform, so I have just select a piece of how it looks like. So we have a column called Hospital which has those 4 rows which repeat until end of the dataframe. I want to transform so that all the data can only be saved on first row which is called prelim_arm_1 and delete the rest of the 3 rows arms.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize data of lists. 
data = {'Hospital':['prelim_arm_1' , '24_hour_review_arm_1','48_hour_review_arm_1',
                    '72_hour_review_arm_1','discharge_informat_arm_1','prelim_arm_1' , 
                    '24_hour_review_arm_1','48_hour_review_arm_1',
                    '72_hour_review_arm_1','discharge_informat_arm_1'],
        'Bug_Hosp':['133', 'NAN' , 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN','133', 'NAN' , 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN'], 
        'code':['G45','NAN' ,'NAN','NAN', 'NAN', 'G45','NAN' ,'NAN','NAN', 'NAN'],
        'cont':['T256','NAN' ,'NAN','NAN', 'NAN','T256','NAN' ,'NAN','NAN', 'NAN'],
        'IPC':['NAN','NAN' ,'NAN','567TY', 'NAN','NAN','NAN' ,'NAN','567Tu', 'NAN'],
        'NO_CT':['NAN','NAN' ,'NAN','NAN', '5667','NAN','NAN' ,'NAN','3456', 'NAN'],
        } 

# Create DataFrame 
df_final = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Print the output. 
print(df_final)
```

**Final dataset** should look like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize data of lists. 
data = {'Hospital':['prelim_arm_1'],
        'Bug_Hosp':['133'], 'code':['G45'],
        'cont':['T256'],
        'IPC':['567TY'],
        'NO_CT':['5667']} 

# Create DataFrame 
df_final = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Print the output. 
print(df_final)
```

The dataset is huge with repeated rows arms but I want for each group of 4 rows, it should only save data on *prelim_arm_1* and delete the other *3 row arms*. so final table will only have *prelim_arm_1* with data per group of 4 arms.

Comment: I think, literally, just ```df[df.Hospital == 'prelim_arm_1']``` as the other fields are 'NAN'.

Comment: They are NAN on some columns but looking at last two rows and last two columns they have data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want first non missing values per each 5 rows use first [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) if `NAN` are strings, else omit this step and then use `groupby` with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) by helper Series created compared `Hospital` column by first value `prelim_arm_1` and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
#if necessary
df_final = df_final.replace('NAN',np.nan)

df_final = df_final.groupby(df_final['Hospital'].eq('prelim_arm_1').cumsum()).first()
print(df_final)
              Hospital Bug_Hosp code  cont    IPC NO_CT
Hospital                                               
1         prelim_arm_1      133  G45  T256  567TY  5667
2         prelim_arm_1      133  G45  T256  567Tu  3456
```

**Detail**:

```
print(df_final['Hospital'].eq('prelim_arm_1').cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    2
Name: Hospital, dtype: int32
```

Comment: So small problem, this data is huge and the row repeat in groups, after the first bunch of rows named this way ```['prelim_arm_1''24_hour_review_arm_1','48_hour_review_arm_1','72_hour_review_arm_1','discharge_informat_arm_1']``` we have another bunch with different data ```['prelim_arm_1' , '24_hour_review_arm_1','48_hour_review_arm_1','72_hour_review_arm_1','discharge_informat_arm_1']``` and it continues in groups till end but I want to move data to only one primary row prelim_arm_1 per each group of arms.

Comment: @LivingstoneM - so it means each group starting by `prelim_arm_1`? Or how is possible distinguish group? Is possible add more data of `Hospital` column and explain how each group looks?

Comment: Yes each group starts with prelim_arm_1 then follows other arms. Let me add more data

Comment: I have added more data to the dataframe in the question